# Mapping multiple result sets stored procedure in EF 5 or EF 6 CodeFirst

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a entity model as below:

```
public Entity
{
    //Properties
}

public Activity : Entity
{
    //Properties
    public Action Action { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Command> Commands { get; set; }
}

public Action : Entity
{
    //Properties
}

public Command : Entity
{
    //Properties
}
```

I have a store procedure that returns List of Activities along with Related Actions and Commands of each Activity. How I can map the result sets of the before-mentioned store procedure in EF5  or EF 6 Codefirst ?
I already used `ObjectContext.Translate` method of which is explained in MSDN article [Stored Procedures with Multiple Result Sets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj691402.aspx).

But the problem is all my entities are derived from `Entity` class and that's why when I used 
`ObjectContext.Translate` for `Activity` .. I can't use it for `Action` and `Command` since It maps the `EntitySetName` of the `Entity` class for `Activity`so if I use it for either `Action` or `Command` it'll raise error. How I can manage that?

Comment: You have to use stored procedure for that, or it is possible to get results with query generated by EF?

Comment: I did use store procedure for that as per the provided link.. but the problem is with mapping the result sets to proper Entity type in EF.

Comment: I did use Linq to Entity but the generated query was terribly time consuming so I had to use store procedure for that as per the provided link.But the problem is with mapping the result sets to proper Entity type in EF.

Answer (score 2):

Stored Procedure with multiple result set is very much possible in EF5 or greater. Here is the link for detailed answer

[Stored Procedure with Multple Result sets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj691402/)

Comment: Hi thanks for the effort but if you cast a look at my question you'll see I have found and gone through the same exact link but it's not workign for me due to the reason I already explained in my question.. so that link which I already provided is not the answer in my case.

Answer (score 1):

This works well as an extention on your IDataReader

```
    public static List<T> MapTo<T>(this IDataReader dr)
    {
        var list = new List<T>();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            var obj = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
            foreach (var prop in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                if (!Equals(dr[prop.Name], DBNull.Value))
                {
                    prop.SetValue(obj, dr[prop.Name], null);
                }
            }
            list.Add(obj);
        }
        return list;
    }
```